# Can i specify specific accounts for single bank in plaid and then just retrieve data for those accounts?

Tags: plaid

I am implementing PLAID Api's in my project, now i want to know can i specify specific accounts for bank to just retrieve data for those accounts because i can have many accounts in one bank and of different category like business or personal etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible. If an institution uses OAuth (and only a small handful in the US do right now), the user can filter out certain accounts, but there is no way for you as the developer to pick which ones to filter out. You can also use the [Select Account flow](https://plaid.com/docs/link/customization/#select-account) to let the user tell you which accounts to pay attention to, but it doesn't prevent data from other accounts from being returned, except in a few special cases that are described in the linked documentation.